# Definite article required or not?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

I am having difficulty deciding whether the definite article is required in the following sentence.

> An indicator of a strong character is (the) person’s ability to compliment the achievements of others.

Comment: You need _some_ kind of article. Zero article will not work there.

Comment: Did you mean [**complement**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/complement) or [**compliment**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/compliment)?

Comment: You need the indefinite article "a" (where "a person's" is equivalent to "one's" in this context). Edit: Looking at it again, I guess it really depends on the context. If what precedes is a discussion of a specific kind of person, then the definite article is more appropriate. But "an indicator of a strong character" seems to imply we're talking about people in general.

Comment: @WeatherVane Corrected :)

Comment: Replace *person's* with *people's* and you can remove the article. But you have to use an article in front of singular count nouns in most constructions (including this one).

Comment: Questions about the use of articles are best asked (or previous postings searched) on English Language Learners.

Comment: Note that the article isn't required before "strong".

Answer (score 2):

Certainly an article of some sort is required here, and I personally prefer `a` to `the`. But you can easily avoid the problem:

> An indicator of a strong character is the ability to compliment the achievements of others.

Answer (score 0):

I think  either  **a**    or   **the** is required in the  context. If you  do not  use  an  article , the  sentence  becomes  ungrammatical

> **An Indicator of  a  strong character  is  a  / the  person' s ability to  compliment  the  achievements  of others.**

I thiink it can be simplified as:

> **An indicator  of  a  strong  character is  a/ the  person's ability to  compliment others' achievements**.

If  you want to talk about  persons in general  you  have to use the  article ** a**. or  if  you want  to  talk about  a particular  person  you have  to  use the  article ** the**

I think the  use of  definite  article   restricts  the  general   sense.and I tend to use   **a** in  the sentence

Answer (score 0):

It is required.

In English, we have what are called [noun phrases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase), and as [described by this source](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/noun_phrases.htm):

> In normal writing, nouns nearly always feature in noun phrases. It is rare to find a noun functioning by itself (i.e., without any modifiers) in a sentence.

Nouns are rarely used by themselves in noun phrases, a notable exception being when we use them as subjects when talking about the attributes of categories:

> Boys are great!
>   Life is tough.
>   Drugs are a problem.